# Remove domain from reCAPTCHA service

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

I signed up at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin when I was setting up a forum page at mysite.com/forum but the method I used added a badge to the bottom right of every page on my site.

The badge looks like [this right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uie86.png).

I dislike the badge and my mobile users are very frustrated about it.

In an effort to remove it, I clicked the trash icon to delete my domain from the reCAPTCHA Admin Console area on Google. Two days later and it hasn't gone away.

I don't even use the forum anymore, yet somehow Google is able to insert an iframe onto every page of my site for some kind of invisible reCAPTCHA.

I didn't add any code to my site. I don't understand how they are doing this. It even shows on Firefox. When I search for how to remove the badge, I only see CSS solutions.

I do not want a CSS solution. I want it permanently gone. As if I never added my domain to their service. Maybe there is a specific amount of time before their service knows I deleted my domain from it?

My site uses Cloudflare and on the first visit you see the badge. Note that I am NOT talking about the challenge page.

**How do I remove the "protected by reCAPTCHA" badge without using CSS?**

Comment: Was this ever figured out?  I posted a similar question before I found this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove reCAPTCHA site on Admin Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172329/remove-recaptcha-site-on-admin-console)

Answer (score -1):

remove
reCAPTCHA
من ال login
from cpanal

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).