# Remove reCAPTCHA site on Admin Console

Tags: recaptcha

Pretty simple. I feel like there's a setting or button somewhere that I'm not seeing.   I have a list of sites I've registered with reCAPTCHA.  I want to delete one on the admin console.  How do I do it?

When I go into the settings on one of the sites there doesn't seem to be a way to delete.

Comment: Reasons for down votes are appreciated :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I was right, there's a delete button I didn't see!  Click the cog at the top to enter the settings of the page you want to delete.  Then there's a delete button in the header of that page.  Hopefully this will save someone some time.  Check it out:

[image]

Comment: That delete button was so out of the way I needed this answer to realize it was there, I don't think they could have hid it any better.

Comment: Thanks! 
ehmmm... in some cases Material Design = baddest UX

Comment: Some more amazing Google UX here. Thanks for this!

Comment: Hilarious. I didn't see it either. Thanks for the answer.